# MySQL queries taking forever to execute

Tags: mysql, join

I am an admitted noob trying to get some traction on a really big patent database.  The query I'm currently trying to run looks like this:

```
select * from generalinfo, assignees 
where year(generalinfo.GrantDate)=2000;
```

Both generalinfo and assignees are tables with over 4 million records, which I know is a lot of data, but the queries are taking hours to execute (when they don't fail due to running out of hard drive space).  The key in both tables is PatentNo if that makes any difference.

Comment: You're not explicitly joining generalinfo and assignees, so the product of the query you have above will be a cartesian join (cross product of the two tables). In your case, that is 4mil x 4mil records!

Answer (score 3):

Anytime you use a function in your predicate, your performance will suffer. This is because indexes can't be used on functions in predicates. An alternative is to use `BETWEEN`. It's also poor practice to use `SELECT *`. You should also avoid implicit join syntax (I'm assuming you know you're using a `CROSS JOIN` which is every row of `generalinfo` being joined to every row of `assignees`).

```
SELECT [column_list]
FROM generalinfo g
CROSS JOIN assignees a
WHERE g.GrantDate BETWEEN '2000-01-01' AND '2000-12-31'
```

Answer (score 0):

> Both generalinfo and assignees are tables with over 4 million records, which I know is a lot of data, but the queries are taking hours to execute (when they don't fail due to running out of hard drive space). The key in both tables is PatentNo if that makes any difference.

Here is the point: while you mention the `PatentNo` column here, you don't use it in the query. If you do a proper query with joining the tables, you'll have a completely different result.

Additionally, the thin Kermit says about functions holds. If you use his `BETWEEN` solution and have a proper index on the `GrantDate` column, you'll see a huge speedup.